# Customizing a bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, custom-bib

I am working on a project that requires the bibliography style to appear like that (in each reference, the 2nd and further lines must appear indented):

[image]

I am using a .bib file that is included on the abntex2 document package. Is there a way to create this specific style of bibliography? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is hanging indentation all that you need to achieve? Which bibliography style do you employ at present? Do you use a citation management package such as `cite` or `natbib`? You wrote, "I am using a .bib file that is included..." -- did you maybe mean to write, "I am using a .bst file that is included..."?

Comment: It's close to the `authortitle`  style of `biblatex`, and it's easy to customise.

Answer (score 1):

To adjust the bibliography item separation distance (`bibitemsep`, which seems to be playing a role in the picture you posted; try with and without) and the indent after each first line (`bibhang`), you can use

```
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5em}    % distance between bib items
\setlength{\bibhang}{1em}         % indent after each first line
```

in your preamble. You can easily adjust those lengths with different values and units. Generally, `em` is recommended, because it depends on your font size.